# How to escape dynamically generated String values in a JCR SQL2 query?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, jcr-sql2

Let's pretend I have a JCR 2 query string that is made like this:

```
String sql2Query = "SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] " +
                   "WHERE [aProperty] <> \" + aValue + "\"";
```

Are there helper methods using which I can escape `aValue`?

By the way, I already know that in SQL2 we can use placeholders for queries and let the framework take care of escaping of values for us, but if I were to create this query dynamically, how can I escape `aValue` to prevent SQL injection as well as construction of broken queries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use placeholders. Even dynamically created queries can use
placeholders.

As for SQL-2, you need to use single quotes, not double quotes. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent]
WHERE [aProperty] <> 'Joe''s Taxi'
```

You only need to escape single quotes, using a single quote escape
character:

```
String aValue = "Joe's Taxi";
String sql2Query = "SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] " +
    "WHERE [aProperty] <> '" + aValue.replaceAll("'", "''") + "'";
```

If you want to use XPath, you can use single quotes or double quotes, but
usually single quotes are used as well (the same as in SQL-2). XPath
queries don't support placeholders currently.

Comment: Thanks. I was mainly looking for an API helper class/method to escape the text for me. Something similar to `QueryEscapeUtils.escapeStringVariable(String s)`.

Comment: The same solution provides with org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.SQL2Parser.escapeStringLiteral("String for escape")
(Can be added with groupId: org.apache.jackrabbit, and artifactId:oak-core)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `org.apache.jackrabbit.util.Text` has `escapeIllegalJcrChars`. Would this help?

More information:
https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.4/org/apache/jackrabbit/util/Text.html